# How to plot orbits by integrating numerically?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to plot the orbits described by the solution:

```
x[ϕ_] = -(1/6)+0.5 Tanh[(ϕ + ϕ0)/2]
```

where the x is the radius and the ϕ0 is the angular variable in the orbital plane.
How could I plot this orbits? If it's necessary more equations here is the complete system of ODEs:

```
r'[λ_] = Sqrt[E^2 - (L^2/r^2) +(2 M L^2/r^3] 

ϕ'[λ_] = L/(r^2)

t'[λ_] = E/(1-(2M/r))
```

where $L$ is the angular momentum, $E$ ia the total energy of the system and $M$ is the mass of the central body.

Ps: Please, can someone edit my question I post the equations in code format, otherwise Stack wouldn't allow me to post.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Is this what you mean? `ParametricPlot[
 x[\[Phi]] {Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Phi]]} /. \[Phi]0 -> 3, {\[Phi], 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}]`.

Comment: Equations are coded with double-equal `==`, assignments with single-equal `=`. -- What does this question have to do with [tag:numerical-integration]? It seems you have a formula to plot and do not have any need of `NDSolve` (nor `NIntegrate`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 PolarPlot[-(1/6) + 
   0.5 Tanh[(\[CurlyPhi] + \[CurlyPhi]0)/2], {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}],
 {\[CurlyPhi]0, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

yielding the following result:

[image]

Have fun!